# Why I get this sql error - SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, prepared-statement

Look at this update query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user u SET u.role_id     = ?
                        , u.name        = ?
                        , u.address     = ?
                        , u.city        = ?
                        , u.phone       = ?
                    WHERE u.user_id     = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([ $userRole
               , $name
               , $address
               , $city
               , $phoneNumber
               , $user_id
               ]);
```

Then I use `after update trigger` that performs updation in the "user" table and keeps the log information in the "user_log" table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_log` ;
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_log`
  AFTER UPDATE ON `user` 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
SELECT NEW.user_id,
       CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s ", columnname),
       oldvalue,
       newvalue
FROM ( SELECT 'name' columnname, OLD.name oldvalue, NEW.name newvalue
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'address', OLD.address, NEW.address
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'city', OLD.city, NEW.city
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'phone', OLD.phone, NEW.phone
     ) data
WHERE NOT oldvalue <=> newvalue;  

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is, above update query is working for me if I not use the trigger. But when I use trigger then the update query is not working and gives an error as follows.

Look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0013124f70c5cb8b6efc8d6ee4ec8a23), then you will find my trigger also working along with update query.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' in E:\projects-new\user_form_submission.inc.php:139 Stack trace: #0 E:\projects-new\user_form_submission.inc.php(139): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\projects-new\user_form_submission.inc.php on line 139
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the received text in the general log file once the SQL query is executed by my php script.

```
220623 12:52:03  11006 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on cp-project
     11006 Query  SET NAMES utf8
     11007 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on cp-project
     11007 Prepare  SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1
     11007 Execute  SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_id = '1' LIMIT 1
     11007 Close stmt 
220623 12:52:04  11007 Query  START TRANSACTION
     11007 Prepare  UPDATE user u SET u.role_id     = ?
                            , u.name        = ?
                            , u.address     = ?
                            , u.city        = ?
                            , u.phone       = ?
                            , u.mobile      = ?
                            , u.whatsapp    = ?
                            , u.email       = ?
                            , u.sex         = ?
                            , u.dob         = ?
                            , u.designation = ?
                        WHERE u.user_id   = ?
     11007 Query  INSERT INTO user_log (user_id,action,old_data,new_data)
SELECT NEW.user_id,
       CONCAT('Changed ', OLD.name, "'s data"),
       oldvalue,
       newvalue
FROM ( SELECT OLD.name oldvalue, NEW.name newvalue
       UNION ALL
       SELECT OLD.address, NEW.address
       UNION ALL
       SELECT OLD.city, NEW.city
       UNION ALL
       SELECT OLD.phone, NEW.phone
     ) data
WHERE NOT oldvalue <=> newvalue
     11007 Query  ROLLBACK
     11007 Close stmt 
     11007 Quit 
     11006 Quit
```

Can anybody tell me what would be problem for this? Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: Does the UPDATE is executed correctly w/o the trigger?

Comment: Yes sir, It is executing correctly without trigger

Comment: The trigger itself cannot produce this error. Especially it cannot produce such error message (it looks like PHP interpretation - MySQL must type like `Unknown column 'name' in 'OLD'` because of precise trigger code). I recommend you to enable General Log on MySQL temporarily and look precise SQL query text received/executed by MySQL and precise error message text produced.

Comment: hello sir, my problem is still unsolved. As you said I tried mysql general log on. The text received after executing the update query is added as an update to my question. To my knowledge in mysql could not get any clue from that text. Sir, when you have time, take a look at this. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see the reason for your issue. Look at Error Log and add rows from it which are relative to the issue. Recommendation: retrieve precise tables structures using `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`; create a fiddle with these DDLs (both tables and trigger), add 2-3 rows to `user`, then execute your UPDATE statement and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I check mysql_error.log file and I can find there is nothing ralated to this

Comment: Sir I just got a little clue. I could not tell if my local server is running MariaDB -v 10.4.13. I tried to run my fiddle from MariaDB again, then the sql error message above can be seen. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c63b122abedf9481d72129bee0d2d87d)

Comment: Local variables usage removes the issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e08258e4980b34a9f108b1cfb4708e85